# Create a plotting loop

Tags: python

I have created this for loop which goes through my 3 dataframes (schedules) and by default plots desire as y-axis.

As the code is in a loop it gives me 3 different graphs, any suggestion how to improve the code so i can plot them inside one graph?

```
def plotter(*schedules, desire='Interest'):
    """
    *results : The amortized schedules
    desire : The y-axis to compare against time in months.
    """
    for schedule in schedules:
        df=schedule.plot(x='Period', y=desire, label= desire)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @9769953 i've updated it and made the loop and variable, anyhow i cannot manage to get the loop to produce the subplot's in one graph

Comment: @9769953 yeah subplot=True was a mistake.
all lines in a single plot and preferbly with different colours

Comment: If i add
```
fig, ax= plt.subplots(1,1) and ax=ax inside the schedule.plot(..)

I get all lines correctly in one graph but i can't call different y values in the function

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want a different column name for each of the schedules, or that the column name is always the same.

Comment: The column name in the schedules is always the same, i have a earlier function that generate different schedules depending on rates etc.

which means that when i call the y-value i want the y value from the respective table to be computed in the graph

Answer (score 0):

Create some dummy dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Interest': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})
dfs = [df, df.copy(), df.copy(), df.copy()]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['Interest'] += 5 * (i-1)  # Offset the dataframes
```

Rewrite the `plotter` function to use the `ax` keyword:

```
def plotter(*schedules, desire='Interest'):
    """
    *results : The amortized schedules
    desire : The y-axis to compare against time in months.
    """
    ax = None
    for i, schedule in enumerate(schedules):
        ax = schedule.plot(x='Period', y=desire, label=f"schedule{i+1}", ax=ax)
```

Call `plotter`:

```
plotter(*dfs)
```

Profit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps me to create the graph as intended but, once i try to call for another variable i.e 'End Balance' i get error. 'str' has no attribute 'plot'

By calling the function with:
```
plotter(schedule1,schedule2,schedule3, 'End Balance')
```

Comment: Nvm, think i sorted it by calling the function by

plotter(schedule1,schedule2,schedule3, desire='End Balance')

Comment: Any suggestions how i can easily rename the lines with schedule1 .. schedule3?

Comment: @VilgotKraft Do you mean in the legend? See my updated answer.